# Why do I only get 100mbit on my Asus GigaX1005?

Tags: linux, ethernet

My GbNIC (Intel 82579LM, kernel 3.0 module e1000e) only connects with 100mbit although it's connected to a 1000mbit port (Asus GigaX1005) via an short (<3m) CAT6 cable.

```
flo-nbook ~ # ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 2
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000001 (1)
                   drv
    Link detected: yes
```

Also forcing has no effect:

```
ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000
```

Is this a known bug in the kernel module? Am I missing something? Or an interoperability problem with the Asus switch?

Comment: This is useful in case anyone else makes the same mistake, but if you really want it deleted we can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Asus's specs on that switch, its only capable of 100mbit.
http://www.asus.com/Networks/Wired_Routers_Switches/GigaX1005/#specifications

> 5 RJ-45 for 10/100Mbps Ethernet ports

Also you cant set ports to 1000mbit, it must be auto-negotiated.

Comment: You seem to be are right. I bought the switch some time ago and assumed because of its name that its gigabit capable. Also the "Advertised link modes" supported my assumption.

Comment: Ya, theyre kinda sneaky. The specs say `1.0 Gbps` but thats the throughput the switch is capable of handling. A 100mbit port on full duplex does 200mbit, and then 5 ports gives you a total of 1gbit throughput.